# How to show a double number which bit is more than 16?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

For example,I have a number which bit is more than 16,I want to show it in the web,I find if I use `.toString ()` directly,it will be failed.

```
double testnumber=0.12345678998765432;
string tnStr=testnumber.toString();
```

I want to return the string which value is `0.12345678998765432`,but it is not return `0.12345678998765432`.But I find if use newtonjson,it is return `0.12345678998765432`.What is the difference between `.toString ()` and `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`?If in winform,how can I change the double to string?